# Changing View on Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin-studio

Currently my view is stuck with my "Watch" outside of my other views:

[image]

Ideally I would like to have my "Watch" tabbed in with my other views such as "Locals, Breakpoints, Threads, Application Output."

Normally this would be as simple as dragging the "Watch" into the other tabbed views. However, I have been unable to do that and it just snaps back to a solo tab.

How do I combine all these tabs? This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! This wasn't as intuitive as it could be:

To conjoin separate tabs, you need to drag the tab to the **CENTER** of the new tab as seen in the picture below.

[image]

Note. Do not try to drag the new tab to the TABBED part. Simply drag it to the center of where you want to conjoin. In the above picture I am dragging the Breakpoints tab into these tabbed views.